# Including Angular dependencies using Gulp (and Browserify)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp

I would like to use Gulp and Browserify with my new angular app.

**Question**: How do I include the angular dependencies in the `app.js` so it doesn't throw a dependency error?

I can't even get it to load with no dependencies but only using the `$stateProvider` in the config as :

```
require('angular');  // It works with a basic declaration, but still gives an error in the browser console - *wierd*
var app = angular
  .module('myApp', [
   // 'ui-router' I want these to be included as well
  ])
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    // This will error and say $stateProvider unknown provider
  });
```

I would like to include the angular services/providers such as `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider` and then also new dependencies such as `'ui.router','ngAnimate','ngResource',...`

I know I have to include the file (with Bower they were all in line in the `index.html` as script includes to the bower location).  Do I link to the `node_modules`?, include it in Gulp?, both? neither?, another node module with `npm install ...`?

My structure:

```
|- app
  |- _css
  |- _js
    |- controllers    *for angular*
    |- directives     *for angular*
    |- factories      *for angular*
    app.js            *main angular js file*
  |- _img 
  |- _css           
  |- views
    |- directiveViews *html specifically for directives*
    |- partials       *html snippets*
|- node_modules       *for npm/node*
...
server.js             *for node to launch*
gulpfile.js           *for gulp*
```

Other Relevant Notes :

- Ultimately trying to get a Angular Ui Router app going.
- I am trying to not use bower, as it seems to be on its way out, and I would like to learn browserify with Gulp.
- I do not know what the `config.js` (i think for gulp) does or if it is needed.
- I am trying to follow along [this](https://omarfouad.com/blog/2015/03/21/advanced-angularjs-structure-with-gulp-node-and-browserify/) tutorial.

Comment: You need to add `ui.router` in your array of dependencies when instantiating you `app` module for `$stateProvider` to be known.

Comment: @HuguesStefanski Then I get `... Failed to instantiate module ui.router due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.router' is not available! You either ...`   How do I get the array to reference the appropriate file(s) ?  I also thought `$stateprovider` was included with angular by default, but that could be a mistake of mine since I have been using `ui-router` from the start....

Comment: I think I missed the module loading part, see the answer below, and I think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Apart from installing the `angular-ui-router` node module with `npm install angular-ui-router`, you need to require this dependency just like you would with angular. So your app might look something like this:

```
require('angular');
require('angular-ui-router');

var app = angular
  .module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
  // $stateProvider will be properly injected here
});
```

Both browserify and webpack figure out what to put in the bundle based on the require calls (or import in case of ES6).